# How to implement two different responses for two different External Systems in Rest API

Tags: java, gosu

Two External Systems (A and B) are there.
When A sends the request - response should be "The system name is A"

When B sends the request - response should be "The system name is B"

How to know which system is sending the request so based on that the API can send the appropriate response?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply ask the system A and system B to pass a client id as a request parameter. You can make a comparison with that to identify which system is calling your API.